# WEKA LibSVM Text Classifier

Tags: text, classification, weka, svm

I am newbie to WEKA. I have written a program to classify Text using LibSVM and WEKA. 
The code is available in [BitBucket Repo](https://bitbucket.org/jaganadhg/wekatextmining/changeset/b1367f7ec8d5d3680adedbf43ffa8b6e0cef396d#chg-src/org/jaggu/ml/weka/WekaSVMTrainer.java)  .

Can somebody tell me whether I am in the right path.

Bet regards

Jaggu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to evaluate your approach to see if your 'on the right path'. Use [cross validation](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code#Classification-Evaluating) to see if the models trained by your approach yield the performance you want.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the responseThanks for the response . I added the following lines in my code Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(filterdInstances);
eval.evaluateModel(svm, filterdInstances);
System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString(true)); 
and i got the results like 

=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances        2000              100      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         0                0      %